# Transformerless supply

Tags: transformerless

I am desigining a transformerless supply with two cap in series .if I measure the voltage across 1st cap it is 80 volts and same for other but net voltage measure across these two caps are 240 How and why??

Comment: what's the value of the caps? What's the loading impedance of your meter? I do hope you're using X2 rated caps!

Comment: I bet you are using 6.8 nF capacitors or very close to that value?

Comment: You've had an hour to answer the comments so I'm voting to close this question as unclear. In future please hang around to answer queries and don't naively expect your question to be 100% answerable when first posted.

Answer (score 6):

The multimeter isn't a perfect open circuit; It (typically) presents as an impedance of something between 100kΩ and 10 MΩ.

When you connect the multimeter across one of the two caps to measure its voltage, you are basically also putting a resistor in parallel with that capacitor, which drops the voltage across it by passing current.

[image]